# Solve $f′(t)=−|f(t)|^rf(t)$ so that $f(t)$ approaches $0$ when $0<r<1$ and does not approach $0$ when $r\geq 1$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find a solution of the differential equation,
>
> $f′(t)=−|f(t)|^rf(t)$ where $f$ is any differentiable function on $t$, so that $f(t)$ approaches $0$ (as $t\rightarrow \infty) $ when $0<r<1$ and does not approach $0$ when $r\geq 1$.

I think there should be a term $r^t$ in $f(t)$ but really struggling to find it exactly because of the modulus sign. Tried variable separable method, but failed. Is it possible to find a solution? Then how? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry too much about the modulus; you can restrict yourself to positive solutions. Since $f(t) = 0$ is a trivial solution to the first order ODE, you know solutions cannot cross the $f=0$-axis, so must be either positive or negative.

Your ODE has a positive solution
\begin{equation}
 f(t) = \Big(f_0^{-r} + r\,t\Big)^{-\frac{1}{r}},
\end{equation}
which exists for all time $t>0$ and converges to zero for all positive values of $r$. However, if we look at the ODE
\begin{equation}
 g'(t) = - |g(t)|^\frac{1}{r},
\end{equation}
then we obtain the solution
\begin{equation}
 g(t) = \Big(g_0^{1-\frac{1}{r}} - \left(1-\frac{1}{r}\right)\,t\Big)^{\frac{r}{r-1}},
\end{equation}
which does have the desired behaviour for $t \to \infty$ as $0<r\leq1$ or $r > 1$.